# electron: Custom protocol example doesn't work in windows

Tags: javascript, windows, file, protocols, electron

- Electron version: 1.4.4
- Operating system: Windows 10 x64

Hello,

i am trying to “hack” the file protocol in `electron` so that i can treat *absolute paths*. On `os x` everything works fine.

On windows, i can’t get the example from the [protocol documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md) to work, it throws an `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` error. I am feeding a path string in the form `atom:///path/to/index.html` and also tried registering `atom` as a standard scheme.

The error occurs at startup when calling `win.loadURL()`.

If I call `file:///path/to/index.html`, the file is loaded correctly (however, subsequent resources with absolute paths fail), but no combination of `registerFileProtocol` or `interceptFileProtocol` worked for me, even if i explicitly return the string `file:///path/to/index.html` in the callback, i get the error message.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [enlight](https://github.com/enlight). Let me share his answer verbatim:

> `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` probably means the path you're passing to the
>   callback is invalid, the callback takes an absolute file system path,
>   not a URL. So calling `callback('file:///path/to/index.html')` won't
>   work, but `callback('C:\\path\\to\\index.html')` should work 
>   (assuming the file exists).